# Spring Security not allowing anonymous HTTP POST request

Tags: spring, security

Below is an example security configuration. It will not allow a POST request on "/user" by an anonymous client (e.g. Intellij HTTP request).

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user").anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

I have also tried permitAll() and the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/user");
}
```

The below configuration doesn't send me to the login page, but still gives me a 403:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/user**").anonymous()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct configuration to allow a single endpoint and all its children to be bypassed, though it unfortunately does not allow you to specify an HttpMethod nor ignore child endpoints (e.g. /user/{id}):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/user").anonymous()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/user");
}
```